# Use Maven to start programs

Tags: maven, jar

I apologize if this sounds to simple (or the fact that there are other links that define this problem) - but I'm a complete beginner to Maven and even Java.

All that I'm trying to do is to run this code to see what it does:

https://github.com/semanticvectors/semanticvectors/wiki/GettingStarted

The Wiki says that uses can either download the .jar file or use the maven repo. I downloaded their .jar file and tried to run it but failed. I use this code:

```
java -jar /home/user/semanticvectors-5.6.jar
```

That .jar file didn't work for me and from other stackoverflow links, it seems that either the .jar file is not setup properly or I have a non-compatitble java version.

In any case, I've decided to try using Maven to get this running. I've installed Maven using:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

It seems to be working as everything was successful in setup. But now I'm not too sure what to do after. This Wiki (linked above) as go to this Maven repo site (https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick%7Esemanticvectors). To my understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong) I thought Maven is a super repository for developers and testers to work from the same code, so I thought I could use Maven as an alternative to running to program. Anyways, I'm open to any suggestions to get the program running to see what it does, thanks.

If you're interested in knowing more about me: I'm running a 16.04 Ubuntu system with Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you can either build the JAR yourself - get the source from SVN and build it (using maven commands, as maven is a build tool), or you can use the existing JAR that is already "prepared" and ready for use in the maven-repository (nexus, in this case).

The result should be the same - if you use the JAR as a dependency in your code (add it to your pom.xml) or if you build it yourself.

You can learn more about Maven and things will be much clearer...